# <,>,/ etc symbols are getting escaped while trying for xss,anyother alternatives for these symbols to carry out the attack successfully?

Tags: xss

Symbols like >, <, / etc are getting escaped any alternative to carry out the xss attack ?

most of the websites are having xss filters

Comment: Please state an explicit question. Such as "How do I fix ..."

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to bypass an XSS filter by either percent-encoding or HTML-encoding the characters that are being filtered.  On the other hand, a properly-written filter is aware of these techniques and can handle them.